# Using javascript in Crystal Reports formula editor

Tags: javascript, crystal-reports, google-translate, formula-editor

How can I go about using java-script in Crystal Reports formula editor ? I wish to write a function that will use [Google Translation API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Translation) to modify the report's data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use JavaScript in the formula editor.  You will need to write a UFL to do the communication with Google.  The function would probably require three arguments: text to be translated, from language, to language.  The function would return the translated text.